Efficient algorithm to construct simple polygon from non-crossing orthogonal line segments
Given a set of $N$ non-crossing orthogonal (vertical and horizontal) line segments on the plane, is there an efficient algorithm to construct a simple orthogonal polygon that passes through all given segments?
All non-crossing segments are internal (endpoint of a segment cannot be a vertex of the polygon). Each side of the orthogonal polygon must contain exactly one internal line segment. All segments' endpoints have integer coordinates.
Motivation: Rappaport proved that it is NP-complete to decide whether a set of points in the plane can form simple polygon passing through the given points if 180 degrees angles are allowed at the given points.


Question was posted on CS SE without getting an answer.
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/168121
